# Activating virtualenv from batch file causes venv in new command prompt

Tags: python, batch-file, virtualenv

I don't know if this is the best wording but I'm trying to get a venv up and running on a new location with a .bat script.

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv venv
start .\venv\Scripts\activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
python run.py
```

But after the activation the virtualenv opens in a new command prompt, therefore the packages don't get installed locally but globally because the command doesn't run in the virtualenv.

I've tried removing the start before

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate
```

but that crashes the .bat.

Can I prevent the batch from opening the new window or make it continue in the new window?

Comment: I don't use virtualenv, but rather I create my virtual environment with `python -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/enviornment`. But an alternative to `/path/to/new/virtual/enviornment/bin/activate` is simply doing a `cd /path/to/new/virtual/enviornment/bin` followed by running `pip3`. Perhaps this will work for `virtualenv`.

Comment: `call .\venv\Scripts\activate`

Comment: @chepner You're right. My bad seems I didn't search thoroughly enough. Using call instead of start solved my problem.